# Make multiple NSScrollViews scroll at the same time

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, nsscrollview

I am developing a Cocoa Application for Mac OSX. I intend to have multiple NSScrollViews and I'd like all of them to scroll at the same time if one of them is selected and scrolled.

I saw for UIScrollView there is a method "scrollViewDidScroll" that I could do this with an iPhone application.

Is there anything similar for NSScrollView or a way to go about doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is going to require that one of the scroll views will need to receive notifications that the other scroll view is being scrolled.

Apple actually provides some [very nice documentation on Synchronizing Scroll Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/SynchroScroll.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003537-SW5), which also has some sample code snippets as part of it.